# TYPO3 Ext. cal: adapting the search form

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

Per default the search form contains the following inputs:

[image]

Instead of the two Inputs "Startdatum" and "Enddatum" i want a selectbox with a month option.

In
typo3conf\ext\cal\Resources\Private\Templates\v2\search_event.tmpl

there are only the post parameters start_day and end_date for the search.

How to realize am month selextbox if i only can select and post a month value ?

Must i make changes here?
typo3conf\ext\cal\Classes\View\SearchViews.php

Can i realize this with an own cal extend extension?

Comment: Which view for cal plugin you need at least (search, month, weeks, day list, ...)? You could try to write your own month select form with parameter tx_cal_controller[month].

Comment: I can build a select width tx_cal_controller[month] instead of tx_cal_controller[start_day] and tx_cal_controller[end_day].

But i must change the function drawSearchEventResult() in SearchViews.php because of the new parameter.

I don't know how to do this in a cal extend extension

Comment: Thats right. But do you really need searchView? The searchView lists events, which matches search filter. ListView also list events, but can take care of params like tx_cal_controller[month] if you add some typoscript. I can add an example here.

Comment: Please add an example. I need a filter for events with category, event owner and month of the year.
I can also use listView for this, but why is the listView better for this?
Eg if i add this as a get parameter in list view, it doesn't work:
&tx_cal_controller[month]=08

Answer (score 0):

Given you use content element of type plugin with view set to 'list' and add your own form select for month, which generates requests with parameter like

```
?tx_cal_controller[month]=08
```

then you can manipulate list results with a typoscript condition to show only events from requested month of current year:

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_cal_controller|month >0]
    plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.useCustomStarttime = 1
    plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.useCustomEndtime = 1
    plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.customStarttimeRelativeToGetdate = 1
    plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.customEndtimeRelativeToGetdate = 1
    plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.starttime = monthstart
    plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.endtime = monthend
[global]
```

To use your own category filter for list view, you need to adapt/extend class \TYPO3\CMS\Cal\Controller\Controller::initConfigs() to invoke a parameter like

```
?tx_cal_controller[category]=2
```

into global configuration like

```
/**
 * Init configurations
 * Change category mode in listview, if category given in GET params
 * Used for category filter by selection
 */
public function initConfigs() {
    parent::initConfigs();
    if ($this->piVars['category'] && $this->conf ['view'] === 'list') {
        $this->conf ['view.'] ['categoryMode'] = 4;
        $this->conf ['view.'] ['category'] = $this->piVars['category'];
    }
}
```

For a working filter of event owner I have no example.

Comment: I'm using TYPO3 7.6.18 and cal 1.10.3.
Basic css styles an no fluid templates.

The month example does not work for me. There is no change in the list view when appending ?tx_cal_controller[month]=08

Can i debug this in the view controller?

The second example works for me, but without extending your class.

Comment: if i add this to my ts:   

`plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.useGetdate = 1`

  

i can change the month via ?tx_cal_controller[month]=08, but in the list view only targets one day, not one month.

Comment: [globalVar = GP:tx_cal_controller|month >0] ...
  plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.useGetdate = 1 ... 
[else] ...
 plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.useGetdate = 0 ...
[global]

Comment: ok, thanks. Now it works.  
But if i add my third parameter: tx_cal_controller[organizer]=1, this doesn't work. The same with tx_cal_controller[organizer_ids]=1.    
The only thing which works with this parameter is the search_view yet

Comment: As i mentioned, for a working filter of event owner I have no example. Also for further filterings (location, etc...). This you should try to invoke in the -initConfigs()- method. But remember, you did start asking for month filtering only.